# Index match. Calculating quota vs the actual booking values

Tags: excel, lookup, index-match

I've an excel file wherein there are 141 sales reps and 14 managers. Those 141 sales people have been assigned to different managers randomly and their quota for a FY.

Sales reps with their managers and quota

[image]

With the help of sumifs and countif I got their yearly quota:

```
=SUMIFS(Quotas!$D$3:$D$143,Quotas!$B$3:$B$143,$I5)
```

[image]

With the help of quota mentioned above I need to derive the actual business that sales reps have achieved.

[image]

I tried xlookup, index match, choose and nested ifs but nothing is working out.

In booking I have more than 4000 entries.

Comment: "I tried xlookup, index match, choose and nested ifs but nothing is working out." please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried using a SUMIFS of F:F with a XLOOKUP in? criteria being XLOOKUP() = G4, something like that.

Comment: I added a column of manager in between sales rep and amount
=XLOOKUP(D2,Quotas!$A$3:$A$143,Quotas!$B$3:$B$143,"NA",0,1)

then later used sumifs to calculate quarterwise business 

=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$4157,$C$2:$C$4157,$M$3,$E$2:$E$4157,L4)